# How to turn newlines into indents with regular expressions

Tags: regex, vim

I have a list that looks something like this:

```
Item 1


Subitem 1

Item 2

Item 3


Subitem 1


Subitem 2



Subsubitem 1

Item 4
```

Pretty much, every top-level item has one newline before it, and each subitem has two newlines, and sub-subitems have three, and so on. I want it in a format similar to this:

```
Item 1
    Subitem 1
Item 2
Item 3
    Subitem 1
    Subitem 2
        Subsubitem 1
Item 4
```

The regex I have been using in vim is this:

For the first level:

```
%s/^$\n\(\t\w\)/\t\1/g
```

For the second level:

```
%s/^$\n\(\t\t\w\)/\t\1/g
```

and so on.

What's the better way to do this without having to run a different regex for each level of the list? I'm trying to use vim to do this, but any *nix solution is fine with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that you can do is to recursively use the following regex :

```
(?<!\n)\n\t*\n
```

Recursively find and replace all the occurrence of this regex

- First pass Replace with : \n
- Second pass Replace with : \n\t
- Third pass Replace with : \n\t\t
- Fourth pass Replace with : \n\t\t\t

...and so on until there is no match for the regex anywhere.

So you don't have to run a different regex every time, but still you'll have to change the replace with part. You can write a small program to recursively do it.

Comment: I have given a normal regex, not something specific to an editor.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what is executing the regular expression.
E.g. Sed won't do the trick as it parses lines. If you are using sed, try to replace it with tr:

```
tr '\n' '\t'
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that I was using vim. updated the question

Comment: In that case, don't forget that vim replaces \n to a visual ^@. Use \r instead! I would recursively call 
`%s/^\([^\n]*\)\n\n/\t\1\r/g`

Answer (score 1):

The Perl way:

```
perl -0777pe 's/\n\K\n+/"\t"x(-1+length $&)/gse'
```

Using `tr` and GNU `sed`:

```
tr '\n' '\t' | sed -E 's/([^\t])\t\t/\1\n/g'
```

Output:

```
Item 1
        Subitem 1
Item 2
Item 3
        Subitem 1
        Subitem 2
                Subsubitem 1
Item 4
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with `:s` and sub-replace-expression (`\=`).

```
:%s/^\n\+/\=repeat("\t",len(submatch(0))-1)/
```

Basically we count the number of `\n`'s and replace them with the same number of `\t`'s.

- `:%s/^\n\+/.../g` find our sequence of `\n`'s
- `%s/.../\={expr}/g` replace the match with the evaluation of expression, `{expr}`.
- `submatch(0)` get the n'th submatch. Same as `\0` or `&` in this case.
- `repeat({str}, {num})` returns a string, `{str}` repeated `{num}` times.
- `len({str})` get length of string, `{str}`.
- `len(submatch(0))-1` decrement length as we want to keep the "good lines" on separate lines.

For more help see:

```
:h :s
:h sub-replace-expression
:h :repeat()
:h :len()
:h submatch()
```